# how to make rows of datagridview vertical with insert enabled

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am working on windows application with `C# 4.0` and `winforms`,I want to make the rows of a `datagridview` vertical, I changed the view like the code below and made the rows vertical but the problem is that it is not a real vertical rows and horizontal columns it is just adding column names to the first column of each row and changes the column name to column index, I want to insert data in the `datagrid` but when inserting data it acts like normal grid(cause i do not actually change the behavior of a `datagrid`) here is my code:

```
 public DataTable vertical_rows(ref DataTable dt)
    {
        var swappedTable = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            swappedTable.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < dt.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            var r = swappedTable.NewRow();
            r[0] = dt.Columns[col].ToString();
            for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][col];

            swappedTable.Rows.Add(r);

        }
        dt = swappedTable;
        return dt;

    }
```

I am wondering how can i change the behavior of `datagridview` for vertical rows and horizontal columns? like a 90 degree rotate? or what is the parallels here?

Comment: check this site for some working code in the future save yourself and do a simple google search respectfully speaking thanks http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19313/Displaying-Vertical-Rows-in-DataGrid-View

Comment: I actually did this my self my problem is not with the viewing data this way and it is about to inserting data like I mentioned, in the link you mentioned it actually does what I already did.

Comment: have you considered using a different `Control` to do this ..? like a ListView or something..? perhaps you could render your table in HTML as well

Comment: How you want `datagridview` handle inserts/updates of your data. Adding row in datagridview = adding column in your datasource. And adding column = adding a row in datasource?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I tried list view as well but the result was the same,you mean that i render HTML table and show it in the application?

Comment: @Fabio yes, but the problem is not with the data source it can be handled as well ,when you have two columns and `n` rows when you want to fill the rows(which are vertical) when you enter data and press enter for example it makes a new column with empty fields which is not the expected behavior when you want to rows to be set vertical

Comment: I am confused.. if you want to add a new row then perhaps you need to move `var r = swappedTable.NewRow();` outside of the for loop if you step thru the code and put a break point you can still use the `Quickwatch` to view the DataTable by clicking on the little magnifying glass

Comment: it will give an empty datatable if i put the  var r = swappedTable.NewRow(); outside the for loop cause i am generating the whole datatable again and for each column as row we should add new row then